# gcloud: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli, python-3.12

When attempting to run the GCP command line tool `gcloud` on MacOS with Python 3.12 the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk-1/lib/gcloud.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk-1/lib/gcloud.py", line 90, in main
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import encoding
  File "/Users/wujames/test-python/google-cloud-sdk-1/lib/googlecloudsdk/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import importing
  File "/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk-1/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/importing.py", line 23, in <module>
    import imp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imp'
```

Any attempt to run gcloud on MacOS with Python 3.12 being used as the default python interpreter on the system's PATH results in the above error. The same error does not occur on Linux or Windows as gcloud bundles its own python interpreter on those platforms.

Comment: it occurs on Windows too, in case the bundled Python unchecked

Comment: During gcloud SDK setup I saw the following: "Google Cloud CLI works best with Python 3.11 and certain modules." Until that says 3.12, consider using the recommended Python version.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone running into this issue, I was able to get around it by setting env variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to my Python 3.10 executable. 3.12 did not work still, I assume anything less than 3.12 will work.

Comment: Can you please how did that? As I tried to do it and it didn't work.

Comment: @Jimit.Gandhi In Windows, I went to my Environment Variables and edited/added a variable for "CLOUDSDK_PYTHON" to both my user and system variables. For the value, I pointed it directly to my python.exe for the 3.10 install, for example - "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

Comment: Thanks Major. I tried same in MacOs but for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: @Jimit.Gandhi Add the following to your `.zshrc`: `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11`

Comment: Exactly. The version of Google SKD I was using was not compatible with Python 3.12. I set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable to python3.10, updated the SDK with gcloud components update and then set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable back to python3.12.

Everything is running normally now.

Answer (score 13):

If you use MacOS you can fix it by:

```
brew upgrade google-cloud-sdk
```

Then

```
gcloud components update
```

Comment: Only works if you installed `gcloud` via Homebrew, see my answer if you get `Error: Cask 'google-cloud-sdk' is not installed.`.

Answer (score 8):

Installing gcloud's supported python versions (3.8 & 3.9) as the system's default python interpreter solves the issue.

If multiple python interpreters are available, setting the `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` environment variable to point to the path of the preferred interpreter will solve the issue. More information is available on the gcloud CLI's MacOS installation page: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#mac

Answer (score 5):

Upgrading `gcloud` to latest version `446.0.0` with `brew upgrade google-cloud-sdk` didn't resolve the issue for me. So running `gcloud components update` was still failing with `No module named 'imp'` error.

1. Upgrade your `google-cloud-sdk` first:

```
brew upgrade google-cloud-sdk
```

2. To resolve this issue, you need to have at least `python3.11` interpreter on your environment. *(You will need to install it if you don't have.)*

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=$(which python3.11)
```

3. Upgrade the components: (Press `y` to continue)

```
gcloud components update
```

4. Then you can able to use `gcloud` without any issues using `python3.12`:

```
unset CLOUDSDK_PYTHON
gcloud version
```

Comment: That's the definitive way to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

Updating `gcloud` to version `452.0.1` or greater resolved the issue for me without downgrading from Python 3.12.

```
gcloud components update
```

After updating, I was able successfully run `gcloud` commands:

```
$ gcloud components list

Your current Google Cloud CLI version is: 458.0.1
The latest available version is: 458.0.1

...

$ python --version
Python 3.12.1
```

**References**

- IssueTracker thread: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/303280713#comment8
- Documentation for updating: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#updating_components

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  Temporarily altering the python version long enough to do the "gcloud components update" worked for me.

Comment: Upgrading from 444.0.0 to 467.0.0 solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: This solution cannot be run by people who have the problem. `gcloud` itself gives the Python imp error, so it cannot update itself. See my answer below for how I solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Support for imp was removed in Python 3.12 (the warning was added in 3.11 apparently).
See: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html

Answer (score 0):

The version of Google SKD I was using was not compatible with Python 3.12. So I set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable to python3.10, updated the SDK with `gcloud components update` and then set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON variable back to python3.12.

Everything is running normally now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a working `gcloud cli` installation but a MacOS upgrade might have updated the Python version and thus `gcloud cli` started failing with the mentioned error.

I followed the [official instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) to install `gcloud cli`, replacing the `google-cloud-sdk` folder I already had. The updated sdk works fine with Mac's default Python 3.12.*.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Copy/pasta into your Terminal

```
brew install python@3.11
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11
gcloud components update
```

---

### Detailed Answer

This answer is for those who have Homebrew installed but did not install `gcloud` via Homebrew (though it should work even if you did). If you did `brew upgrade google-cloud-sdk` and got

```
Error: Cask 'google-cloud-sdk' is not installed.
```

Do

```
brew install python@3.11
```

it will either install it, upgrade it, or leave it alone, but the point is you'll have it.

Then do

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11
```

right there in the Terminal, no need to mess with .zshrc. You only need it for the next command.

Then do

```
gcloud components update
```

which should now run because you have an old Python for it.

After the update, you no longer need that `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` reference, because the new `gcloud` runs with the latest Python (for now).

Go ahead and open up a new Terminal window and do `gcloud`, it should work now.